# How to pass data to component if it's Prop is mentioned as child - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am working in a task where I need to pass the data to table. The table has it's own data type and prop. I need to follow the same when I am applying the logic. Now I am trying to pass the data dynamically. But when I am trying to pass the data dynamically I am not getting the values in table body. Any one can guide me how to populate the data dynamically. I need to follow the below format when I am working with the table component

```
**Table Props:**

1. Table PROPS- Prop: Children Type: Node default:[] (Desc: the child
    content for table consisting of eithera Table Header or Body)
      
 2. Table Header Props- Prop: Children Type: node default:[]

 3. Table Header Cell props - prop:children type:node default:[](Desc:
    content to display for column header)

 4. Table Row Props - Prop: Children Type: node default:[] (Desc: child
    table cells to be placed within the tr)

 5. Table Cell Props - Prop: Children Type: node default:[] (Desc:
    content to be displayed for row cell)
```

**My Code**

```
<Table paddingStyle="compact">
      <Header>
      <HeaderCell key="Name">Name</HeaderCell>
        <HeaderCell key="ID">ID</HeaderCell>
        <HeaderCell key="Group">Group</HeaderCell>
      </Header>
      <Body>
        {mockData.forEach((element) => {
            element.cells.forEach(cell => {
                return (
        <Row key={element.key}> 
        <Cell>{cell.Name}</Cell> // In console I ma getting undefined
         <Cell>{cell.ID}</Cell> // In console I ma getting undefined       
         <Cell><Batch {cell.Group}/></Cell> // In console I ma getting undefined
        //Batch component will be imported
        </Row>
                )
        })
        })
  }
```

**JSON Data**

```
[
{
    "key":"k-01",
    "cells":[
      { key: '0',  Name: 'ABC' },
      { key: '1',  ID: '123' },
      { key: '2',  Group: ['1', '2'] },
    ]
```

]

**Table Component Format**

```
<Table>
    <Header>
      <HeaderCell key="NAME">Name</HeaderCell>
      <HeaderCell key="ID">ID</HeaderCell>
      <HeaderCell key="Group">Group</HeaderCell>
    </Header>
    <Body>
      <Row key="0">
        <Cell key="NAME">ABC</Cell>
        <Cell key="ID">1</Cell>
        <Cell key="Group">I, O</Cell> // in the form of label or React-bootstarp badge(Example)
      </Row>
    </Body>
  </Table>
```

Answer (score 0):

using `map` would be better option here ,
you are getting undefined because of the way `forEach()` returns the value

Like `map` , the `forEach()` method receives a function as an argument and executes it once for each array element. However, instead of returning a new array like map, it returns `undefined`.
as you can see in answer below

**code:**

```
    const myAwesomeArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
myAwesomeArray.forEach(x => x * x)
//>>>>>>>>>>>>>return value: undefined
```

Comment: even after I am doing with this by mapI am not getting the values. It's giving undefined.

Comment: yes as when the Name will be there like `cell.Name` >> ABC , the `ID` and `group` will not be there so those will throw `undefined ` your array of objects is such that , you need to try different approach the current approach to set them in table won't work , undefined is the expected behaviour in this case